# Close bootstrap-vue modal with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a bootstrap-vue modal and try to close it in my click-function.

```
this.$refs['my-modal'].hide()
```

but get the following error:

```
Property 'hide' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.
Property 'hide' does not exist on type 'Vue'
```

I tried with jquery also

```
$('#my-modal').modal('hide');
```

With error:

```
Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'
```

Comment: have you tried bootstrap-vue api ? https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/#using-thisbvmodalshow-and-thisbvmodalhide-instance-methods

Comment: the first part is the exact copy from the link you sent. Seems that the typings aren't working, and I can't figure out how to make them work in typescript.

Comment: Bootstrap-Vue does not use jQuery, so the jQuery methods will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest version of BootstrapVue (2.0.0-rc.21 +), you can use the newer `this.$bvModal.hide(id)` method to close a modal with the specified `id`. `$bvModal` is typed, so it should work fine with Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

When `refs` are not working for me in `Vue+Typescript`, I sometimes cast the `ref` to an `HTMLElement` or disable type checking by using `any`.

```
(this.$refs['my-modal'] as HTMLElement).hide()
(this.$refs['my-modal'] as any).hide()
```

Comment: Didn't work as I guess Jquery isn't an option with bootstrap-vue as Troy mentioned. I will however probably be using this in other places, so thanks.

Comment: The typescript cast will work as well.. as it is hard/unwise to augment `Vue.prototype.$refs` type, as it would make `.hide()` appear as valid on any ref.